# Вывод строк из .txt файла

Tags: php

Как найти слово в строке .txt файла, а затем вывести эту строку? Подобных строк несколько, нужно, чтобы на выходе выводились несколько строк, в которых было найдено слово.

```
<?php
$date_today = date("mdy");
$today[1] = date("His");
$file=file("listofplayers.txt"); 
$open=fopen("listofplayers.txt","a");
$nickname = $_GET['nickname'];
$text=$_GET["nickname"]." ".$_GET['x']." ".$_GET['y']." ".$_GET['z']." ".$_GET['skin']." ".$date_today.$today[1]." ".$_GET["playerColor"]; # на что нужно изменить 


 if (strpos(file_get_contents("listofplayers.txt"), $_GET['nickname']) !== false){
    fclose($open);
    $open=fopen("listofplayers.txt","w"); 
    $file = file('listofplayers.txt');

    for($i = 0, $j = count($file); $i < $j; $i++) {
        $str = strpos($file[$i], $_GET['nickname']);
         if (strpos($file[$i], $_GET['nickname'])) { 
         echo $str;
        }
    }

} else {
    fwrite($open,$text."\r\n");
    echo ("added");

}

fclose($open);
```

?>

Comment: С недописанного вопроса остался, забыл заменить. Сейчас изменил.

Comment: Добавил код. Этот вариант мне чистит весь .txt файл..

Comment: Подправил код, чтобы можно было воспроизвести результат его работы: [Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3cb5cf8c25c886c4c4709778c5dcea4d52c18f43)

Comment: Добавил весь мой код в топик, с вашими изменениями, но результат тот же(

Comment: Посмотрите пример из предпоследнего камента - вот на его основе и правьте ваш код.